# Can I save a job listing without having it published?

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I'm trying to write up a job listing and send it through to my co-workers for their stamp of approval.

But I can't seem to save a job listing without having published it and forking out the money. Is this really the case? Or am I missing a feature here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but right now there's no way to "save" a listing without publishing it first. The only suggestion I can make is to write the listing up in a Word document and have your co-workers review that. Sorry for the inconvenience, but it's definitely on the TODO list!